# Excel VBA:Looping a Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to convert a vlookup formula I wrote to VBA code that will loop through each cell in a column. The vlookup is part of an if statement, which works fine on its own. The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to tell the vlookup function what cells to look for data in so that it can be generalized to the entire loop. The formula is the following

=IF(K114<>"",K114,VLOOKUP($A114,comp!$A$1:$D$136,2,FALSE))

Here's what I have for the VBA

```
Sub Ranking()

Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("K2:K120")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Else: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(HELP HERE,ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:D136"), 2, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what to put where I put "help here" to tell it to refer to the text in column A of the same row it's looking in. I'm also not sure if this is the right way to loop for this situation?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you need a vba code for this or can a worksheet formula work?

Comment: Unfortunately it's part of a much larger VBA code and can't be a formula. I just wrote the formula first to guide my thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "Help here", look at your formula where you swap out K114 for A114. That means you need to go from current cell in column K back to column A. That can be done with an offset of the current cell by 10 columns to the left to get to column A.

```
Sub Ranking()

Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("K2:K120")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Offset(0, -10).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:D136"), 2, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```